# Graylog vs Fluentd

Tags: open-source, fluentd, graylog

Out of available open source log management tools, I have come across these two but couldn't figure out which one to use. I tried searching articles for Graylog vs Fluentd but couldn't find.

Could someone suggest which one would be good for the following criteria,
* production master-slaves architecture with not so high end hardware, like single core processor   with 4GB RAM and decent drive size to accommodate logs
* log search via UI
* alerts based on rules
* minimal setup (if possible)
* dynamically add/remove slave hosts from VIP

Thanks in advance
Mirza

Comment: Hey, this isn't such a bad question. Because this question, I got the answer (below) I was looking for. So, +1 for that. :grin:

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I tried searching articles for Graylog vs Fluentd but couldn't find.

Because Graylog and Fluentd are different layer tool.

Fluentd is a streaming event collector. Fluentd doesn't have a storage and visualization UI like Graylog.
Graylog is a log management tool based on Elasticsearch, not event collector.

Fluentd can be a data source of Graylog so not "vs".
Here is an one example Fluentd and Graylog combo: http://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/graylog2

Comment: maybe a better "vs" are ELK vs Graylog vs Splunk